# Striding across members of a vector of structures

Tags: c++, vector, struct

Is there an easy way to stride through an STL vector of structures by member? In other words, if I have a struct like this:

```
struct foo {
    double x, y, z;
};
```

in a vector `std::vector<foo> bar(20)`, can I stride across the array picking out x from each struct?

I've tried this, but it does not seem to work:

```
for (int i=0; i<20; ++i)
{
   double xx = (&bar[0].x + i*sizeof(bar[0]))->x;
}
```

Why doesn't that work? Does `sizeof(bar[0])` not account for the padding between structs?

**Note**: I realize this is a really silly way to access x in a loop, but this loop is just an experiment to see if the stride works or not.

If it helps, I want to do this so I can pass bar to a library routine that accepts a pointer and a stride as constructor parameters to its own internal datatype. I could, of course, convert my code from AoS to SoA, but I don't want to do that unless I absolutely have to.

Comment: sizeof won't include padding because padding can depend on what comes before and after in a data structure too.
You could perhaps do "int size = (char*)&bar[1] - (char*)&bar[0]" instead? Not sure how legal that is though which is why this is a comment not an answer.

Comment: Whenever I see something "clever", I wonder why someone would want to make something _more obscure_ and _less maintainable_.

Comment: Again, I really need the start and the stride to pass to a 3rd party library over which I exercise no control. The loop is just an empirical test to confirm that it works, not an attempt to be clever.

Comment: "Does `sizeof(bar[0])` not account for the padding between structs?". It does account for it, the problem is the pointer type as Andrey and user1735003 say. There is guaranteed to be no padding between members of an array or a vector, and any padding *inside* `foo` is included in `sizeof(bar[0])`.

Comment: @jcode: it's legal provided the vector has at least two elements, and it's guaranteed to be equal to `sizeof(foo)`.

Comment: Ok, I wasn't thinking about this properly, please disregard my comment above, it doesn't achieve anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I'd compute the stride directly instead, using something like:

```
struct point {
    double x, y, z;
};

int main() {
    point points[2];

    std::cout << "stride = " << (char *)(&(points[1].x)) - (char *)(&(points[0].x)) << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`&bar[0].x` is a pointer to double. You're adding `i*sizeof(bar[0])` to it.

The effect is that the address stored in the pointer increases by `i*sizeof(bar[0])*sizeof(double)` which is not what you expect.

A correct expression is

```
&bar[0].x + i*sizeof(bar[0])/sizeof(double)
```

Comment: It's unlikely, but permitted by the standard, for `sizeof(bar)` to not be a multiple of `sizeof(double)` even though `bar` has a `double` member. And of course it's especially unlikely for this particular class, since it has no members that aren't `double`s.

Answer (score 0):

&bar[0].x is a pointer to double. To add the appropriate shift, you would need to cast it into char*, then double* again.

```
     double xx = *reinterpret_cast<double*>(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&bar[0].x) + i*sizeof(bar[0]));
```

In anycase, you should really consider using standard algorithms for your purpose.

Comment: I need the stride and the initial pointer as a parameter for a 3rd party library. It's really the stride (and the initial pointer) that I'm after. The loop is just an empirical test.

Comment: Ok. Then it's all here: the stride is simply `sizeof(foo)`, no need for arithmetics there. And you can start at `reinterpret_cast<char*>(&bar[0].x)`. I personnally like the use of `reinterpret_cast`. It advertises clearly here that we are dealing with non-standard, low-level tecniques.

Comment: What about padding? sizeof(foo) was the first thing I tried, and it didn't work, hence the change to sizeof(bar[0]).

Comment: It didn't work, so you changed to `sizeof(bar[0])`... and it still didn't work because that wasn't the reason it did not work :) sizeof(foo) is equivalent to sizeof(bar[0]) in the present case. It should work fine.